# SQLite with VB.NET Value cannot be null (Help)

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, insert, null

i have a table "tblAuthors" in a database with following schema (ID Primary Key Autoincrement, Author_Name Varchar)

table is empty. i am trying to insert a record into the table. heres my code

```
Public Sub insertData()
    Me.mystr = "INSERT INTO tblAuthors (Author_Name) VALUES (@Author_Name)"
    modAdoDB.SetConnection()

    Me.mySQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(Me.mystr, modAdoDB.con)


    Me.mySQLiteCommand.CommandText = Me.mystr
    Me.mySQLiteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author_Name", frmAddAuthor.txtAuthorName.Text)
    Me.mySQLiteCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    Me.mySQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    frmAddAuthor.Close()
    MsgBox("Author record has been added.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Library")
    modAdoDB.CloseConnection()
End Sub
```

i get the error message Value cannot be null 
parameter name: s

p.s i can read from the database.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the following line `Me.mySQLiteCommand = con.CreateCommand()`.

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå i get database is locked when i remove the line Me.mySQLiteCommand = con.CreateCommand()

Comment: Jess, you need to open the connection.  Call `Me.mySQLiteCommand.Connection.Open()` before `Me.mySQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're building a command:

```
Me.mySQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(Me.mystr, modAdoDB.con)
Me.mySQLiteCommand.CommandText = Me.mystr
Me.mySQLiteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author_Name", frmAddAuthor.txtAuthorName.Text)
```

And then *immediately* replacing it with another command:

```
Me.mySQLiteCommand = con.CreateCommand()
```

According to [the documentation](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection~CreateCommand.html), `CreateCommand()` can be used in place of the `SQLiteCommand` constructor(s), but you'll still need to set your `CommandText` (and any necessary parameters).

Basically, there's no need to use *both* the constructor *and* `CreateCommand()`.  One or the other would be fine.  So you can just remove this line entirely:

```
Me.mySQLiteCommand = con.CreateCommand()
```

Comment: When i remove this line <code>Me.mySQLiteCommand = con.CreateCommand()</code> i get the message database is locked

Comment: @darksyfer: Did you ever open the connection?  For example: `Me.mySQLiteCommand.Connection.Open()`.  Take a closer look at the examples in the linked documentation.

Comment: yes.. connection is open 'con = New SQLiteConnection(CONNECTION_STR)
            con.Open()'

Comment: @darksyfer: When do you do this?  (It's not in the code provided, but it really should be.)  Is it the same connection object?  When you debug this, what is the runtime state of the connection object when you try to execute the command?

Comment: @darksyfer: To clarify, you should be creating/opening/using/disposing your database objects in as small a scope as possible.  It looks like this method is using objects which have a shared scope with other methods.  This can cause problems (which you're discovering now).  The overhead of creating new connection and command objects is minuscule compared to the risk of re-using the same ones in multiple contexts.

Comment: i tested the connection state after opening the connection and before the insert procedure by using 'code' MsgBox(modAdoDB.con.State.ToString) 'code' The connection is open.

Comment: @darksyfer: Are you able to run other commands on the database?  Open other connections?  Does something outside this application have it locked?  Maybe there's an undisposed connection still hanging on to the database?  (Refer to my previous comment about appropriate object scope.)  We're getting well outside the scope of the original question and starting to just use Stack Overflow in place of a debugger, which isn't really how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: there is no other application locking the database.. i will look into your previous comment.. thanks